# What is wrong with the export of my npm packaged vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I have a small local npm package (`fomantic-ui-vue`) whose main `js` is

```
import Vue from 'vue'
// Import vue component
import  button from './elements/button/button.vue'
import  buttonGroup from './elements/button/button-group.vue'

console.log('--------- package called begin ------------------');
console.log('Register: '+button.name)
Vue.component(button.name, button);
console.log('Register: '+buttonGroup.name)
Vue.component(buttonGroup.name, buttonGroup);
console.log('--------- package called end ------------------');

export const components = {
        button,
        buttonGroup,
    };
export const test = () => {
    console.log('--------- TEST ------------------');
};
```

In my test application I have

```
import FUI from '../../fomantic-ui-vue/dist/main.js'
console.log(FUI)
FUI.test()
```

1. The first line has to be somehow correct because in the browser shell I see `package called begin` and so on.
2. `console.log(FUI)` gives `{}`. Where are test and components?
3. for `FUI.test()` I get the error `TypeError: _fomantic_ui_vue_dist_main_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.test is not a function` Where the `a` comes from? what is wrong?
4. If I comment `FUI.test()` out to avoid the error I get the error that the vue component `fue-button` is not registered, thus I conclude that the npm package registered it in some other place

These are many errors but I think that they are all connected.

**EDIT**

```
const myTest = () => {
    console.log('--------- TEST ------------------');
};

export default {
    test: myTest,
    components: {
        button,
        buttonGroup
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using name export, so in order to use the `test` function you should import it as so:

`import {test} from '../../fomantic-ui-vue/dist/main.js';`

If you want to use it with a dot notation the in your `main.js` the export should be an object with the each key referencing on of the functions:

```
...
const myTestFunc = () => 'test';
const aComponent = () => Vue.component(..);

export default {
   test: myTestFunc,
   component: aComponent
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I opted for the second variant, see my edit. But `console.log(FUI)` is still empty and `FUI.test()` gives `TypeError: _fomantic_ui_vue_dist_main_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.test is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `library` and `libraryTarget` in the webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    library: 'fomantic-ui-vue',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
```